# Structuring Raw Clinical Trial Data into columns with pandas for Machine Learning

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-modeling

I am tasked with modeling data from 3 different tables to fit into a machine-learning model

I am observing 1300 patients, who are taking medication, getting lab results, and responding to verbal surveys.  Information is recorded every week for 24 weeks.

My goal is to feed the data into a model that will predict outcomes for medication efficacy.

The data was given to me in 3 tables.  Here are what the tables look like

Table 1

| PatientID | Week | Medication | MG_dose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1.0 | 32 |
| 2 | 2 | 2.0 | 20 |

Table 2

| PatientID | Week | Test 1 | Test 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1.0 | 0.0 |

Table 3

| PatientID | Week | Survey Q1 | Survey Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.0 | 1.0 |

I'm trying to structure the data where each patient is in their own column as follows

| Clinical Data | Patient1 | Patient2 | Patient3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Week1 Med | 1.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 |
| Week1 Dose | 32 | 20 | 32 |
| Week1 test1 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| Week1 test2 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| Week1 Survey Q1 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| Week1 Survey Q2 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 |
| Week2 Med | 1.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 |
| Week2 Dose | 32 | 20 | 32 |
| Week2 test1 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| Week2 test2 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| Week2 Survey Q1 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| Week2 Survey Q2 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |

I initially tried to use the .join() function in pandas to aggregate data from the 3 tables.  The data was relatively raw and unformatted.  After joining the tables, my test results increased in quantity by 400%, so the numbers are totally off.

I tried to pivot the results from rows to columns; the table created a nested index with a 24-week table for each medication (see photo) which is way too wide for analysis.  There were also a lot of nan values which are challenging to impute in that structure.

I am researching a solution to build some automation, using loops to collect the data from the 3 different tables and map to the appropriate row in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape, here is one option with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) + [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)/[`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
from functools import reduce
 
tables = [Table_1, Table_2, Table_3]
 
tables = [t.drop_duplicates(subset=['unique_ID' , 'patient_ID', 'Week'], keep='first')
          for t in tables]
 
out = (reduce(lambda a, b: a.merge(b, on=['unique_ID','patient_ID','Week'],how='left'), tables)
 .melt(['unique_ID','patient_ID','Week'])
 .assign(**{'Clinical Data': lambda d: 'Week'+d.pop('Week').astype(str)
                                       +' '+d.pop('variable')})
 .pivot(index='Clinical Data', columns='patient_ID', values='value')
 .rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
)
```

Comment: I got the code in #2 block to work; however, there is no loop, so it only created the column for 1 paitient.  Is there a way you can revise the code to loop through all patients?

Comment: The first option did not work; I keep getting error stating there are duplicate rows, cannot reshape...

Comment: You don't need a loop, the `concat` step is merging all datasets. Also, just saying "it doesn't work" is not helpful, you have to provide a reproducible example of data that is not working. If you have an error about duplicates, this means that your data has duplicates which isn't the case in the provided example, it's easy to handle by how to do it depends on the data. Show the data.

Comment: Thanks for the update, you might want to add the code as edit to your question for clarity ;)

Comment: @DanHerman thank you for you edit, I wanted to change it a bit but there is a bug that won't allow me to edit. Could you please edit the bottoms part with the [following](https://pastebin.com/Xh53TvcT)? I changed a bit the method to remove the duplicates to make it more efficient and easier to handle.

Comment: I made some improvements to the dataset and the code works perfectly now.  Very impressive how you came up with that so fast.  Are you able to share your learning technique?  Are you completely self taught or have you taken some advanced courses in python and data wrangling.  My goal is to develop a similar skillset to yours, I would appreciate any advice you can provide for building skills.  Cheers

Comment: I'm self taught. #1 advice: read the docs/source; #2 advice: code, fail, code again ; #3 advice: read the docs (again) ;)

Comment: That is precisely the response I expected!  :D. I will certainly take your advice!   Happy coding!

Comment: You do any work with advanced indexing?  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html